# Insert emojis in mysql 5.5 with java/tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, emoji

I'm develop an app java/tomcat/mysql that consume the twitter api, but when i need insert a tweet with emojis in my table my app show an error :

### ----------------------------------------------------------------

```
Caused by: com.genexus.GXRuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x98\xF0\x9F...' for column 'TweetText' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1072)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3563)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3495)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2693)
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------------

I try to follow several solutions proposed here without success :( (mysql configurations basicly)

Can anybody help me ??
Thanks!!
Bruno

Comment: you using a proper charset/collation for everything? the error suggests not.

Comment: Thanks Marc but, how i see this?

Comment: check the collation on the table/field (e.g. `show create table foo` will show that), then check your connection logic in java to make sure you're specifying the proper charset there as well

Comment: Ok thanks! The column: 
 `TweetText` varchar(190) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat webapp/WEB-INF/lib:

i chaged

mysql-connector-java-5.1.11-bin.jar

for this

mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar

and...it worked!